# Jquery click event not working for an overlay with buttons

Tags: click, jquery

I am having a box with an image,on which when a hover **event** is fired I show an overlay with share buttons for social media like FB,twitter,pinterest etc.
Now,when the user clicks on the overlay portion I want him to be redirected a details page of the image and if he clicks on any of the social media buttons subsequent action should be performed.This is what I tried

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(".over").click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.followBtn')) {
        //this should not trigger if a click occured on one of the links
            console.log('herhererhreh');
            e.stopPropagation();
    }else{
        window.location=$(this).find("a.overClick").attr("href");
            //alert('in else!!');
    }

});
```

This is the HTML for the same overlay div with the buttons

```
    <div class="over">
        <div class="twitter"></div>
        <div class="facebook"></div>
        <div class="pintrest"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="followBtn">Follow Vendor</a> </div>
    </div>
```

`.over` is the class of the overlay `<div>` and `.followBtn` is the class of the button on the overlay.
If I click on the overlay it works fine,but when I click on the button over it,it goes inside the `if` but executes multiple times,i.e I get 10-12 console.log outputs in the console window.
I am not able to figure out the issue.Any inputs or links would be helpful.

**UPDATE:** I got the problem to some extent,it is b'coz of the class that the console.log prints multiple times(**I have multiple images and on click the event is triggered on all of them**).My question is how can I pass `this` to the target so that I get only the current button to execute the event? OR do I need to do it on id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? .over is highest level of the DOM that your event handlers would apply to, then you have a selector that tells you what within '.over' you are interested in. $(this) inside the handler refers to the target of the event.

```
$(".over").on('click', '.followBtn', function(e){
    //this should not trigger if a click occured on one of the links
    console.log('herhererhreh');
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on('click', 'a.overClick', function(e) {
    //console.log('in else!!');
    window.location=$(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: The problem was resolved but I forgot to add an answer!Thank you for the answer